# why i get this error when i try to run mu sign in function in flutter?

Tags: flutter

E/flutter ( 8448): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
E/flutter ( 8448): 
E/flutter ( 8448): ^
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORywg.png)

Comment: Please provide the code as a part of the question here instead of attaching an image. Here is more info on why you should not post images of code [More info...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

Encode the body data when post method is used

```
var res = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: jsonEncode(data));
```

Comment: it do not work for me

Comment: Have you tried passing the api-key if there is one and content-type in headers?

Comment: nope i did not try it.

Comment: Please check with the backend developer who has provided the API. Ask them about what is required in the headers.

I received a PORT number issue when I checked it on postman (Error: Port should be >= 0 and < 65536. Received). A backend issue

Comment: okey gonna do it .ty